# Graded poset of Isotones

Tags: combinatorics

$A,B$ are finite graded posets. $\text{Iso}(A,B)$ denotes the set of isotones from $A$ to $B$. I wonder if $\text{Iso}(A,B)$ is a graded poset. My intuition tells me it is although I can't clearly see a way to construct a proof because of the many different cases that can take place. I think there is a maximal path in $\text{Iso}(A,B)$ of length $n+m$ if $n,m$ are the lengths of maximal paths in $A$ and $B$ and my idea is to show that any maximal path will have this length. I'm not sure if I can make this precise or if I am correct!
$A$ has $n+1$ levels and $B$ has $m+1$ levels, so construct a maximal path by increasing as little as possible at each step to cover $n+m+1$ levels. Assuming this can be makde precise, how can I show every path has this length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\iso}{\operatorname{Iso}}$For each $f\in\iso(A,B)$ let

$$r(f)=\sum_{a\in A}\deg_B f(a)\;.$$

If $f,g\in\iso(A,B)$, then $f$ covers $g$ iff there is an $a_0\in A$ such that $f(a_0)$ covers $g(a_0)$ in $B$ and $f(a)=g(a)$ for all $a\in A\setminus\{a_0\}$. Thus, if $f$ covers $g$, then

$$\begin{align*}
r(f)&=\sum_{a\in A}\deg_Bf(a)\\
&=\deg_Bf(a_0)+\sum_{a\in A\setminus\{a_0\}}\deg_Bf(a)\\
&=\deg_Bg(a_0)+1+\sum_{a\in A\setminus\{a_0\}}\deg_Bg(a)\\
&=1+\sum_{a\in A}\deg_Bg(a)\\
&=1+r(g)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $r$ is therefore a rank function for $\iso(A,B)$.